# GMAT: LEO to GEO with Electrical Thruster simulation?

Tags: electric-propulsion, gmat

I would like to get a simulation from LEO to GEO with an electrical Kick-Stage.

GMAT seems to be able to do it.
Is there any Script/Scenario already written?

The aim is to perform a parametric study on a basis of the scenario example.

Comment: [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12822/12102) mentions an electric propulsion add-on for GMAT. I don't know if it's helpful or not. There's also some links [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44002/12102).

Comment: Not really. I saw a lot of papers dedicated to the transfer topic LEO to GEO but never any GMAT file linked to the study. I supposed someone could have it?